# Mongo (doesnt run through browser)

Tags: php, mongodb, ssl, https

MongoDB is not giving off any error when trying to run through the browser, 
gives a 500 internal server error.

**Things I have tried:**

- checking php modules to make sure its running, **and it is.**
- checked to see if it ran internal from within the server command line
- "php myfile.php" and it works

Server has a domain name using an SSL, so its https:

I have tried catching the error but that also does no good tried couple of ways with no luck.

Finally caught an error which makes no sense since the new Mongo driver is loaded, as it works when I run the file directly from console as apose to browser

'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in httpdocs/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 87

[image]

Comment: Check your error logs? 500 will usually log something. If there's nothing in your logs, maybe double check your error reporting settings too.

Comment: I caught and error, added it to the post